# screen is displaying wrong colors after dual booting 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, color-management, color-depth

I have a Dell inspiron 17r which has an Intel hd graphics 4400 GPU dual booted with Ubuntu and Windows 8.

When I first tried Ubuntu without installing my screen was green instead of the usually orange glow. I just assumed I would need to download a package to get better graphics after the install in order to fix this problem. I decided to install it and I did so with accepting the 3rd party add ons for media and color support.

After I restarted to check if everything worked, Ubuntu had its normal orange background and the colors were normal. I restarted again to check windows and everything was okay.

Now for some reason, whenever I load Ubuntu I have the original problem of horrible discoloration and was wondering if anyone knows what could have gone wrong?

NOTE: I restarted my computer in a fail safe graphics mode (recovery option) and the color is normal. However when I restarted my computer in the normal mode it goes back to the screen color below.

NOTE2: after entering "apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-video-intel mesa-utils" into the command line the console outputted:

xserver-xorg-video-intel:
  Installed: 2:2.99.910-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2:2.99.910-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2:2.99.910-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
mesa-utils:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8.1.0-2
  Version table:
     8.1.0-2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages

NOTE3: here is the pasted xorg file : http://paste.ubuntu.com/7581271/

Here's a screenshot of my issue (taken with my phone):

[image]

Comment: What graphics driver do you have?

Comment: Seth, I have an Intel HD graphics 4400.

Comment: Does this happen in the guest account? or just another account?

Comment: I have only used my primary account to log in. I just tried the guest account and encountered the same problem. It seems that when my computer boots something is going wrong with my graphics driver. When I start in the advanced options mode my graphics seem to be working great.

Comment: Can you upload `Xorg.0.log` to http://paste.ubuntu.com and link us here? Also, what is the output of `apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-video-intel mesa-utils`? Please [edit] it into your question.

Comment: Information has been updated